# What differs between parentheses and curly in std::tuple?

Tags: c++

Well today I met a werid behavior when using `std::tuple()` and `std::tuple{}`.

Here is an easy demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#define   rd   ({ int       x = (std::cin >> x, x); x; })

template <typename... Args>
void log(const Args &...args) { ((::std::cout << args << ", "), ...); }

auto main() -> int {

    auto [a, b] = std::tuple(rd, rd);
    auto [c, d] = std::tuple{rd, rd};

    log(a, b, c, d);

    return {};
}
```

Run:

```bash
 echo '1 2 3 4' > input
 clang++ -std=c++17 demon.cpp
 ./a.out < input
 g++ -std=c++17 demon.cpp
 ./a.out < input
 cat demon.cpp
```

And I got 2 different results: `1, 2, 3, 4` and `2, 1, 3, 4`. That's out of my expectation. I turned to my friends and got the reply of "The macro `rd` is a unspecific behaivor". However, I am still confused with this answer after learning something about **unspecific behaivor**.

Comment: Note that the `({ ... x; })` syntax you used is non-standard. It's better to use a lambda: `[]{ ... return x; }();`, which does the same thing. But in this case, a function template should be preferred to a macro.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I noticed that juts now.. That's a <https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html>..

Comment: Even when replacing the statement expression with a lambda call this technically has undefined behavior (not only unspecified) by itself. You are writing to `x` before its initialization is complete, which was made UB with C++20. Declare the variable properly and then read into it in another statement, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friends are correct.

The unspecified behaviour occurs because the evaluation order of function arguments is not specified, it can happen in any order and can change between calls. Meaning the order of `std::cin` is not guaranteed. The compiler is free to reorder them as it sees fit. This applies to `std::tuple()`, hence the incorrect output.

On the other hand for braced-init-list, the order is fixed left-to-right, therefore `std::tuple{}` is safe and the output is guaranteed.

Furthermore, in `rd`, having braced-statements in expressions is not standard C++ so you are at the mercy of your compiler. I would seriously recommend macro-less refactoring, hiding `std::cin` in an expression seems like asking for trouble.

Why not simple `read_int()` function or generic `read_T`? Then you can generalize to `read_Ts<T1,T2,T3...>` with explicit sequencing. For example:

```
template<typename T>
T read_T(){
    T x;
    std::cin>> x;
    return x;
}

template<typename...T>
auto read_Ts(){
    return std::tuple{read_T<T>()...};
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea! I'd like to try that. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: @PatrickyTau Added an example :)